# App UI design: elegant solutions for weblinks in app

Tags: iphone, ios

I need some pointers on how to provide links in app to sites like Facebook, My website etc... As the image shows having buttons like the one saying "visit somesite.com" looks real ugly and unprofessional. For this specific project I wanted the links to show up at bottom of a scrollable Table View. But I am at a loss on how to do so elegantly. If I were only to link to Facebook/Twitter etc.. I could easily just have used their logo´s as a button since everyone is known with their logo. But for my own website I don´t know. Can I get some recommendations?

[image]

Comment: since when is stackoverflow for ui-design questions?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom view in a XIB, with several UIButtons that serve as the links. And get some nice artwork for the UIButton's backgroundImage. Then, load that custom view from your nib in `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`

Something like:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

   NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomNib" owner:self options:nil];
   UIView *footerView = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

   return footerView;
```

}

You'd probably need to implement `tableView:heightForFooterInSection` as well so that your entire custom view can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Contacts app just shows the URL itself in a table cell. Could that work?